# c++ pointer crashing the application

Tags: c++, pointers

This code is to convert from input string to binary. But the pointer `tempPointer` in `dataToCode()` function is crashing the application. Please guide. Thank you.

```
int main(void)
{
string text;
    cout << " Enter the text/code you want to convert: ";
    cin >> text;
dataToCode(text); 
}

string* asciiToBinary(string input) {

    string binaryArray[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {

         binaryArray[i] = bitset<8>(input[i]).to_string();
         //cout << binaryArray[i] << endl;
    }
    string* tempPointer = binaryArray;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {

        //cout << *(tempPointer + i);
    }
    return tempPointer;

}

void dataToCode(string input) {

    string binaryCode[5];

    string* tempPointer = asciiToBinary(input);

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        //binaryCode[i] = *(tempPointer + i);
        //cout << binaryCode[i] << endl;
        cout << *(tempPointer + i);
    }

}
```

Comment: Well you need to validate your pointer by using `if (tempPointer)`. That would be a good thing to do.

tempPointer is pointing to an array of 5 element but you are looping on the size of input. Are you sure that `input.length()` is not bigger than 5?

Comment: @Ceros `tempPointer` will never be a valid pointer.

Comment: @Nathan, what should I do?

Comment: @Ceros, I only put in string of 5 character long. It works in asciiToBinary function but the pointer does not pass too dataToCode function.

Comment: Well since you know wha the size of the array should be just use a `std::array<std::string, 5>` and you can return that from the function.

Comment: @Peter, you are creating your array in asciiToBinary as a local variable. As soon as you exit this function, this array does not exist anymore.

Comment: The above link by Nathan helped me solve it. string* asciiToBinary(string input) {
 
 string* tempPointer = new string[5];

 for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {

   tempPointer[i] = bitset<8>(input[i]).to_string();
   //cout << binaryArray[i] << endl;
 }
 

 
 return tempPointer;
}